# Alter WooCommerce product short description with an ACF field

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, advanced-custom-fields, hook-woocommerce

Im trying to add an ACF WYSIWYG field after product short descriptions in Woocommerce. Ive added the following to functions.php but it shows the ACF field on the category page too???

```
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description','ts_add_text_short_descr');
function ts_add_text_short_descr($description){

if (get_field('extra_short_description')) { 
$extra_desc = get_field( 'extra_short_description' );
return $extra_desc;
}
}
```

I then stumbled across another suggested code which works, but if a product has no custom ACF field then it breaks like there is a missing div:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_single_product_summary', 2 );
function custom_single_product_summary(){
global $product;
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_start', 'custom_single_excerpt', 20 );
}

function custom_single_excerpt(){
global $post, $product;
$short_description = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );
if ( ! $short_description )   
return ;

if (get_field('extra_short_description'))
$extra_desc = get_field( 'extra_short_description' );

?>
<div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description">
    <?php echo $short_description .$extra_desc; ?>
</div>
<?php
}
```

Any ideas what im missing on the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

Your first function code should need to be like:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description','ts_add_text_short_descr');
function ts_add_text_short_descr( $short_description ){
    global $post;
    
    $extra_short_description = get_field( 'extra_short_description' );
    if ( ! empty($extra_short_description) ) {
        $short_description .= $extra_short_description;
    }
    return $short_description;
}
```

Then your other functions should need to be like:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_single_product_summary', 2 );
function custom_single_product_summary(){
    global $product;

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_single_excerpt', 35 );
}

function custom_single_excerpt(){
    global $post, $product;

    $short_description = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );

    $extra_short_description = get_field('extra_short_description');
    if ( ! empty($extra_short_description) ) {
        $short_description .= $extra_short_description;
    }

    if ( ! empty($short_description) ) :
    ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description">
        <?php echo $short_description; ?>
    </div> <?php
    endif;
}
```

It should better work.

Comment: The first function didn't work but the second did. Brilliant thanks.